# Sobrecarga do operador = em c++

Tags: array, c++, orientação-a-objetos, sobrecarga, heap

Estou tendo um problema ao implementar a sobrecarga do operador = em uma classe heap.

```
  Heap& Heap::operator=(const Heap& outro){
  printf("chamei atribuição\n");
  this->escreve();

  Heap *h = new Heap(outro);
  printf("htemp\n");
  h->escreve();

  return *h;
}
```

Por exemplo: chamo h3 = h1 na main, onde os mesmos são classes heap, que possuem um vetor.
Quando faço a impressão dessa heap intermediaria, dentro da sobrecarga, os valores estão corretos, porém, após o objeto ser devolvido para a main, permanece inalterado, com o valor que inicialmente  estava, ou seja, com o valor que h3 estava antes da chamada de sobrecarga.

Espero ter sido claro em relação ao problema. Obrigado Desde já.

Comment: Estou meio enferrujado em C++ mas acho que não é correto retornar um objeto de heap (alocado com new). Além do mais, a ideia do retorno em operator= é retornar *this. Não entendo pq criar outro objeto.

Answer (score 0):

O código apresentado tem alguns problemas. São eles:

1. O retorno do operador de atribuição (`operator=`) deve ser, na maioria esmagadora das vezes, `*this`. Não vou entrar nos detalhes de quando isso pode ser diferente, mas pelo nível da pergunta eu apostaria que você se enganou ao retornar uma referência para outro objeto;
2. Seu código provavelmente está vazando memória. Baseado na sua pergunta não vejo sentido em fazer uma alocação de um novo objeto no operador de atribução;
3. Dentro do operador de atribuição geralmente os valores do objeto `outro` são atribuidos ao objeto `this`. Isso é tão simples quanto atribuir uma variável a outra: `membro = outro.membro`;

Dito isso, sugiro trocar o código do seu operador de atribuição para:

```cpp
Heap& Heap::operator=(const Heap& outro){
    // Aqui você atribui os membros do objeto "outro" aos membros do objeto "this".
    membro1 = outro.membro1;
    membro2 = outro.membro2;
    membro3 = outro.membro3;
    membro4 = outro.membro4;
    return *this;
}
```

Se você quiser passar a responsabilidade de "copiar" as variáveis do `outro` para o método `escreve()` não há problema nenhum, mas você deve passar a referência do objeto de origem. Exemplo:

```cpp
Heap& Heap::operator=(const Heap& outro){
    printf("chamei atribuição\n");
    this->escreve(outro);
    return *this;
}
```

É claro que para isso funcionar você deve antes modificar ou sobreescrever o método `escreve()` que você já implementou.

PS: O uso do "prefixo" `this->` é opcional.